# how to include use of node_modules in rollup compile

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rollup

I repeatedly get this message and I am trying to include the d3.js into my distribution file.

> Treating 'd3.js' as external dependency

I've tried using this plugin

```
import includePaths from 'rollup-plugin-includepaths';

var includePathOptions = {
  paths: ['node_modules/d3/d3.min.js'],
  include: {
    d3: 'd3'
  },
};
```

what am i missing?

Comment: [`rollup-plugin-node-resolve`](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve)?

Comment: @gcampbell not according to http://fengshuo.co/2016/03/10/integrate-with-rollup-and-es2015-in-amd-project/

Comment: only both worked for me: `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` & `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` but apparently some modules from the internet are authored so poorly, the problem might reside with them and not us poor importing souls

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Note:** This is for **d3js v4** (I'm not sure its possible with v3)

You need to use [rollup-plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve) to make rollup aware of dependencies in node_modules.

You install it via `npm install --save-dev rollup-plugin-node-resolve`
(Note: I'm new to all this, the babel plugin might not be necessary)

**rollup.config.js**

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  entry: 'path/to/your/entry.js',
  format: 'umd',
  plugins: [
    babel(),
    nodeResolve({
      // use "jsnext:main" if possible
      // see https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/jsnext:main
      jsnext: true
    })
  ],
  sourceMap: true,
  dest: 'path/to/your/dest.js'
};
```

It's necessary to use `jsnext:main` otherwise you will get errors like `Export '<function>' is not defined by 'path/to/node_module/file.js'`

Taken from a post on [integrate with rollup and es2015](http://fengshuo.co/2016/03/10/integrate-with-rollup-and-es2015-in-amd-project/)

This is also documented in [rollup issue #473](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/473) (**note** it refers to the old name of this plugin rollup-plugin-npm)

Then you can run rollup via `rollup -c`

You also need to "roll your own" d3 module with just the bits you need. That way you can still use examples from the web with `d3.*` prefixes. I was originally importing the relevant bits into my client code but there is no way to merge all these into one namespace.

Start with [d3 master module](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/index.js) and paste all the exports that you need in your code into a local `./d3.js` file

**Example roll-your-own d3.js**

```
/* 
 re-export https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/index.js for custom "d3" implementation.

 Include only the stuff that you need.
*/

export {
  ascending
} from 'd3-array';

export {
  nest,
  map
} from 'd3-collection';

export {
  csv, json
} from 'd3-request';

export {
  hierarchy,
  tree
} from 'd3-hierarchy';

export {
  select
} from 'd3-selection';
```

**Import your hand rolled d3**

```
import * as d3 from "./d3"
```

As you import more of d3 you only need to keep your `./d3.js` in sync and your client code won't care.

Remember you will need to re-run rollup after any changes.

Comment: can you give an example how to achieve this in d3 version 3.x

Comment: Sorry, no. I dont think v3 has been modularized properly to allow you to do this stuff. But I'm no javascript expert.

Comment: Is this possible via the CLI?

Comment: Yep it is: http://rollupjs.org/guide/ down by Using config files and Getting started with plugins

Answer (score 13):

FYI `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` is deprecated, you should use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-node-resolve

```
npm install @rollup/plugin-node-resolve --save-dev
```

rollup.config.js:

```
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: 'main.js',
  output: {
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  plugins: [nodeResolve()]
};
```

Start Rollup with config file and watch mode:

```
rollup -c -w
```